# Web Scraping using network request with nodejs

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler

I've just been assigned a task involving network requests ( sending get/post requests ) in nodejs, for example to get .php or .json files.

I have searched through the web but no luck. Is there a guildline? Where do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to send http (https) requests form Node.js, there are many options:

**1. Use the built in [http module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html)**

This is the more low level way of doing things and I would not recommend it, if you are new http with Node. You would use this approach when you need full control over the request or you really need speed.

**2. Use a 3rd party library**

This is the more common way of sending http requests. There are many http libraries for Node.js few of which are:

- [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) (deprecated)

Request is one of the most used http request libraries, but since it has been deprecated for a while now, It shouldn't be used in new software.

- [Axios](https://axios-http.com/)

Axios is a Promise-based http client.

- [SuperAgent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent)

Similar to Axios, SuperAgent is a Promise-based http client, but it has useful functions for this like [URL query parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

- [Got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got)

Got is also a Promise-based http client, but it's less verbose than other http clients.

After you choose your preferred option, you should have no trouble finding documentation for it.